# EntityFrameworkCore 5.0.9 Extension Method with eager loading Include does not work without Load();

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have the following code:

```
public static class IntegrationServiceExtensions
{
    public static IQueryable<T> LearningObjectContainerIncludeNestedProperties<T>(this IQueryable<T> query) where T : LearningObjectContainer
    {
        query.Include(x => x.Bases)
            .Include(x => x.LearningObjectives).ThenInclude(x => x.Classifications)
            .Include(x => x.Classifications)
            .Include(x => x.ContainerPropertyImplementations);

        return query;
    }
}

//Include does not work
public async Task<LearningObjectContainer> GetLearningObjectContainer(int id)
{
    var query = _applicationDbContext.LearningObjectContainers.LearningObjectContainerIncludeNestedProperties();

    var learningObjectContainer = await query.FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id == id);

    return learningObjectContainer;
}

//Include works
public async Task<LearningObjectContainer> GetLearningObjectContainer(int id)
{
    var query = _applicationDbContext.LearningObjectContainers
        .Include(x => x.Bases)
        .Include(x => x.LearningObjectives).ThenInclude(x => x.Classifications)
        .Include(x => x.Classifications)
        .Include(x => x.ContainerPropertyImplementations);

    var learningObjectContainer = await query.FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id == id);

    return learningObjectContainer;
}
```

[image]

[image]

Working:

[image]

[image]

It does not matter if I run the code asynchronous or synchronous.

The only way I made the extension method work is by using `.Load();` (explicit loading).

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/explicit

```
public static class IntegrationServiceExtensions
{
    public static IQueryable<T> LearningObjectContainerIncludeNestedProperties<T>(this IQueryable<T> query) where T : LearningObjectContainer
    {
        query.Include(x => x.Bases).Load();
        query.Include(x => x.LearningObjectives).ThenInclude(x => x.Classifications).Load();
        query.Include(x => x.Classifications).Load();
        query.Include(x => x.ContainerPropertyImplementations).Load();

        return query;
    }
}

public async Task<LearningObjectContainer> GetLearningObjectContainer(int id)
{
    var query = _applicationDbContext.LearningObjectContainers.LearningObjectContainerIncludeNestedProperties();

    var learningObjectContainer = await query.FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id == id);

    return learningObjectContainer;
}
```

[image]

Why can I not use eager loading when using an extension method?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/eager

I tried to use split queries with eager loading but it did not work.

```
public static IQueryable<T> LearningObjectContainerIncludeNestedProperties<T>(this IQueryable<T> query) where T : LearningObjectContainer
{
    query.Include(x => x.Bases)
        .Include(x => x.LearningObjectives).ThenInclude(x => x.Classifications)
        .Include(x => x.Classifications)
        .Include(x => x.ContainerPropertyImplementations)
        .AsSplitQuery();

    return query;
}
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/single-split-queries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this method should be:

```
public static IQueryable<T> LearningObjectContainerIncludeNestedProperties<T>(this IQueryable<T> query) where T : LearningObjectContainer
{
    query = query.Include(x => x.Bases)
        .Include(x => x.LearningObjectives).ThenInclude(x => x.Classifications)
        .Include(x => x.Classifications)
        .Include(x => x.ContainerPropertyImplementations);

    return query;
}
```

It was just missing the query re-assignment to the `IQueryable` result /w Include. ("query = ")

Comment: Late night coding, totally missed that. Thank you very much!

Comment: Yeah, it certainly happens. :) It was such a well laid out question with the various things you tried I was double-checking if "could it really be the missing assignment?"   The `.Load()` versions would have worked because the DbContext would be tracking all the related entities by the time the actual query did materialize, filling all the references in.

Comment: Haha thank you! N00b errors can still trick you after all these years! :D